# Flag for comment declined

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

This is the question: [XPages arhitecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746346/xpages-arhitecture)

I have flagged a comment under the question with: "its not spambot - delete this comment please"

My flag was declined.

Was it correct declined?

Comment: Which option you selected in flag ?

Comment: @Vigbyor - flag -> other...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I declined your flag.

Specifically, you asked for that comment to be deleted because it's "wrong". It may need to be deleted, but there's no indication that person is 'wrong'.

Even if they were wrong, there are thousands of comments on Stack Overflow that I could delete for the very same reason.  I could spend so much time deleting all the wrong comments, I'd probably never get to anything else.

Given this user's history, it's not inconceivable to think that the commenter was correct, or at the very least, justified in commenting how they did.

What you can't see is that there are *several deleted answers* where the user posts the same text.

Comment: "Even if they were wrong, there are thousands of comments on Stack Overflow that I could delete for the very same reason" isnt it part of moderators job? Clear not only to delete comments... but if its not enough time to make SO better than some new moderators should be hired

Comment: I delete comments when they need to be deleted. I love to delete comments.  This comment does not need to be deleted, and if the user posts more questions of very poor quality, it's a sign post that someone thought it could be a spambot, or something untoward could be going on.  Unfortunately, the OP for that question hasn't done anything to convince anyone otherwise, but that's a whole 'nother issue.

Comment: Ok my question is cause I cannot see that author has already created many such a questions.  The best solutions was to delete it - the question - before the answer was given =)

Comment: +1 for taking ownership of the OP's question.  I really like that!

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, yes.

The comment is neither offensive, nor spam. It might be unconstructive, but hardly needs to be deleted by anyone other than its poster (which you can address, if it really bothers you).

Comment: That is what I mean - is not constructive at all

Comment: Be that as it may, it doesn't appear to me to be the sort of thing that requires a moderator's intervention.

Answer (score 1):

We should not flag for moderators to delete a comment if it is *wrong* same as answers. Instead you could argue with him via comments. So it was a correct declined.